# Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm getting the following error:

```
Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.
```

My component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router'
import Notifications from 'react-notification-system-redux';

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      invite_token: this.props.match.params.token,
      FormSubmitSucceeded: false,
      inviteRequestSubmitSucceeded: false
    };
  }

  ....

  inviteAlreadyUsed() {
    const notificationOpts = {
      message: 'Invitation already used!',
    };
    this.props.createNotificationSuccess(notificationOpts);
  }

  render() {
    const { invite } = this.props;

    if (invite && invite.status === "completed") {
      this.inviteAlreadyUsed();
      return <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/' }}/>;
    }

  ...
```

Any suggestions on how to avoid this warning? Is this not how you would handle a redirect?

Comment: can I see your constructor?

Comment: @HanaAlaydrus added

Comment: Your example doesn't show where you're setting state... the warning tells you that you're calling it in a constructor or in a render method. You'll have to find where this is happening and refactor the ```setState```

Comment: the createNotification does the setState

Comment: The notification system uses redux: https://github.com/gor181/react-notification-system-redux

Comment: @AnApprentice post your entire component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.inviteAlreadyUsed();` in render -> reducer updating a state -> it call new render -> `this.inviteAlreadyUsed();` -> reducer update a state and again and again...

Just don't call `inviteAlreadyUsed` in render.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you should bind the `inviteAlreadyUsed()` function. You can use arrow function `() => {}`.

```
inviteAlreadyUsed = () => {
    const notificationOpts = {
       message: 'Invitation already used!',
    };
    this.props.createNotificationSuccess(notificationOpts);
}
```

Second, seems like you set the state with props in constructor. Setting it in `componentWillMount()` might be a better approach.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      invite_token: '',
      FormSubmitSucceeded: false,
      inviteRequestSubmitSucceeded: false
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({
      invite_token: this.props.match.params.token
    })
  }
```

Comment: sorry, what's different here?